# Compact way to display weekly schedule?

Tags: info-visualisation, time, timeline, infographic

So, basically I need to display the weekly schedule for classes. I would like this to be quite compact, so I want to just show if the class runs in the morning/afternoon/evening for each day (I will determine the actual time ranges at some point).

So that means, if arranged in a grid, there are 21 cells (see attached image). I'll probably include the actual times on mouseover/click in a tooltip, eg 14:00 - 16:00.

There must be a more efficient/compact way of displaying this information than a grid of 21 cells, surely? If anyone has ideas/experience, please do let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT:** For a bit of context, this needs to be compact because I am displaying these courses as search results, so I need some kind of system in place as a "quick overview" of what the scheduling is.

[image]

Comment: What's the context for this? Why does it need to be more 'compact'? One way to reduce space would be to contract the day names down to initials - "M" "T" "W" "Th" etc. Another way would be to transpose the table so that the days run vertically. It's a visual illusion, but it appears more compact, and will look much better on portrait mobile views.

Comment: @AlexP I updated the original question with some context.

Comment: Is there a need to have three different colours for the class time? The position that they are on the grid already gives the user the information.

Answer (score 1):

[image: An example of how transposing the data gives the illusion of a more compact table]

An example of how transposing the data gives the illusion of a more compact (and mobile-friendly) table

Answer (score 1):

I have made a couple of assumptions, but this is the most compact version I can think of given the most relevant information that needs to be displayed:

- **Days of the week**: A three letter label is probably the shortest and least confusing way to indicate days of the week (avoids the duplicate T and S)
- **Order of the week**: A line to separate weekdays from weekends to allow the user to distinguish those sections easily
- **Class time**: The position in the grid already indicates this so we can eliminate the different colours. Since not all the slots are always filled, we can also use the label (these can be made smaller) in the grid so the user doesn't have to scan back to the top. This could be replaced with actual values in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remember having worked on something similar in the past. One of the options is to use grain view. Just like the Google Calendar App, you can have multiple views that reveal finer detail as you 'zoom in' (switch views). That'd also mean redoing your layout. You can even reveal the time details in the finest grain.

Comment: Can you please provide more information or screenshots? I _specifically_ do not want to create a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

No need to transpose the table either - you can make it much more compact in the same orientation:

[image]

Apologies for the super quick 'n' dirty mockup... you could, of course, make that even more compact still.

Comment: I agree, there's no direct requirement to transpose it, however I don't think it conveys the information quite as plainly. If it were an hourly breakdown of the day, it would work to have the time along the y-axis. But because it's broken into three chunks, it seems less intuitive and scannable. Perhaps that's just my personal preference though.

Comment: Agreed, there is a subjective nature to it... but I like how your more vertical format allows for better mobile scaling. I was really just playing devil's advocate with this one, to show that "John Doe" doesn't HAVE to swap the axes to make it work :-)